# How to solve for a line intersecting a parabola but you don't know the gradient of the line

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

Find the set of values of m for which the line
$y = mx + 4$
intersects the curve
$y = 3x^2 -4x +7$
at two distinct points.

That's the question and I'm really struggling to figure out how to solve it. Please help

Comment: Subtract one equation from the other. Figure out which $m$ values give two solutions, which is where the discriminant is positive.

Answer (score 1):

We solve $$mx+4=3x^2-4x+7\implies3x^2-(4+m)x+3=0$$ The discriminant is thus $$b^2-4ac=(4+m)^2-36>0$$ for two distinct roots. This means that $$(4+m)^2>36\implies \cdots$$ Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you so much. Just to check. +2 or -10 right?

Comment: You have got the values right. But remember that this is an inequality so you should have $$x<-10\quad x>2$$

Answer (score 0):

solve the equation $$mx+4=3x^2-4x+7$$ for $x$
and solve the equation $$m^2+8m-20=0$$ for $m$